# Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfe

Tags: android

This is my error that i run on a mobile device and this is my Build. Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.medianova.doctorfinder"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.37.0'
    api 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.37.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation  'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.yesidlazaro:GmailBackground:1.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.5.jar')
    //database
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I searched a lot but I don't have any solution about this issue.
I use android studio 3.1.0 and Gradle 4.4.

I also this error shown at the bottom of build tab.
MultiDex error is indicated when i run on mobile device.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
```

Comment: it is very hard to know that. so first, you check the whole application and then run.

Answer (score 0):

it builds with these versions:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"

    implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module:"support-v4"
    }
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7"
    implementation "com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5"

    implementation "com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1"
    implementation ("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }

    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0"
}
```

also see [Migrating from Firebase JobDispatcher to WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb) ...